# apache mod_rewrite - rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have a problem with an  mod rewrite rule in the WOULD NOT WORK area :)
I have an Project site witch is just an ajax return site.
So i like to open my site on sitename.com/my-test/project/test.html and would have a rewrite to sitename.com/my-test/project.html?index=test.
I know after my rewrite the rewrite rules of the cms must going his work. Im not sure maybe this is the problem and they cross or crash.

If i browse the URLs via browser all will work just fine, only the rewrite rule would not work and i become total crazy and cant find the problem.

So i hope someone can help me.

## REWRITE CONFIG in .htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #### WOULD NOT WORK ######
    # REWRITE AJAX PROJEKT
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}% ^my-test/projects/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.html$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^my-test/projects/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.html my-test/projects.html?index=$1

    ### WORK CORRECTLY ####
    # REWRITE RULE FOR SEO FRIENDLY IMAGE MANAGER URLS
    RewriteRule ^files[0-9]*/imagetypes/([^/]*)/([^/]*) index.php?rex_img_type=$1&rex_img_file=$2

    # DON'T REWRITE IF REAL FILE, FOLDER OR SYMLINK EXISTS
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    # EXCLUDE SPECIFIC FOLDERS FROM REWRITE ENGINE
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/files[0-9]*/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/assets/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/media/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/redaxo/.*

    # REWRITE ALL OTHER REQUESTS TO INDEX.PHP
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

and i also have tested

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}% ^/my-test/projects/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.html$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/my-test/projects/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.html my-test/projects.html?index=$1
    #OR JUST
    RewriteRule ^/my-test/projects/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.html$ my-test/projects.html?index=$1
    #OR
    RewriteRule ^/my-test/projects/(.*)$ my-test/projects.html?index=$1
    #AND CORRECT
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/my-test/projects/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.html$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/my-test/projects/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.html my-test/projects.html?index=$1
    #AND ---
    RewriteRule ^my-test/projects/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.html my-test/projects.html?index=$1 [L]
```

I dont find the answer, so i realy hope someone can help me

Thank you all

ng
moxx

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}% ^my-test/projects/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^my-test/projects/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.html my-test/projects.html?index=$1
```

You have an extra `%` at the end of your condition: `%{REQUEST_URI}%`. That means it must be the request URI followed by a `%`, and you text on the right ends with `html`, which means this condition will always fail.

Additionally, the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable **starts with a `/`**. Note that the leading slash is gone when used to match the pattern in the rewrite rule.

You actually don't need the condition at all.

```
RewriteRule ^my-test/projects/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.html my-test/projects.html?index=$1 [L]
```

Comment: @user1807046 See the rule at the end of the answer again, you were missing a capture group (the parentheses)

Comment: thx also not working :((( only a RedirectMatch is working put this is not SEO fine -> RedirectMatch ^/my-test/projects/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.html http://sitename.com/my-test/projects.html?index=$1

Comment: @user1807046 Do you have multiviews turned on? Try adding a `Options -Multiviews` somewhere in your htaccess.

Comment: the fail is the SEO plugin of the CMS, it takes the REQUEST_URI of the Header and turn via php to the correct output. So if i just rewrite the URL the REQUEST_URI in the Header is the old URL and the CMS is bring me to the wrong page. I just can fix it if i rewrite the php code :-/ or i make a redirect not a rewrite. Thanks for your help